# Would you still be addicted to something if you lost your memory of being addicted to it?

Tags: memory, long-term-memory, addiction, drugs

If someone was addicted to something, it could be substances/gambling/sex etc... and then  they lost their memory. It could be just losing the memory of the addiction or full blown global amnesia losing everything and having to start from scratch. Would they still be addicted to it?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. What do you know about Amnesia? How does it affect memories? We work differently to many SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful.

Comment: Substance dependence has overlap with, but is yet very different with gambling addiction. This question is overly broad therefore and susceptible to opinion-based answers as it is kind of a theoretical thought experiment rather than a question based on existing evidence. Adding your own research, as suggested above will focus the question and embed it in a framework reducing the chance of mediocre discussion-type answers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I don't know much about amnesia and how it works. I tried google but I keep getting results for drug induced amnesia. I can't seem to word/filter it so that it brings up results for studies on people who've had amnesia and how that's affected their addiction

Comment: The movie-style amnesia isn't really a thing, if that's what you're thinking of.